# How can I see the normal data of a face in Blender 2.9?

Tags: normals

I'm looking for a way to see the normal data of a face, represented as x, y and z in Blender 2.9x. Sounds simple, but I can't find the option anywhere. I seem to remember having the option in 2.79.

Just to clarify: I don't want to see the normal. I want the data.

Comment: I’m not sure you can have it display the numeric data in the viewport, but you can probably get to it with the python API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ZargulTheWizard said, scripting was needed. It turned out I had the script saved in a file from years ago. I'm a bit reluctant to post the script as I'm fairly certain I didn't write it myself, but I can't find the source when searching. So in order to help others I'll post it here. If you are the author, please let me know and I'll give credit accordingly.

[image]

This script will create an additional property in the "Normals" menu of the "Object Data Properties" tab:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

def draw_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    me = context.object.data

    if me.is_editmode:
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        if bm.faces.active is not None:
            row = layout.row()
            col = row.column()
            col.prop(context.window_manager, "active_face_normal", text="", expand=True)
            row.prop(context.window_manager, "active_face_normal", text="")

            if context.window_manager.active_face_normal != bm.faces.active.normal:
                context.window_manager.active_face_normal = bm.faces.active.normal

    else:
        p = me.polygons
        if p.active is not None:
            row = layout.row()
            col = row.column()
            col.prop(p[p.active], "normal", text="", expand=True)
            row.prop(p[p.active], "normal", text="")


def upd_normal(self, context):
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(context.object.data)
    bm.faces.active.normal = self.active_face_normal.normalized()

def register():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_normals.prepend(draw_func)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.active_face_normal = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(subtype='DIRECTION', precision=3, update=upd_normal)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.DATA_PT_normals.remove(draw_func)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.active_face_normal



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```